# How does one override an existing zsh keyboard completion?

Tags: linux, autocomplete, zsh, opensuse

I would like to enable zsh to autocomplete modules for yast2 (an OpenSuSE control panel), but it seems to already have some things defined. I can run

```
compctl -k "(hello world)" nonexistantprogram
```

just fine, but

```
compctl -k "(hello world)" yast2
```

doesn't work at all. Some things for yast2 seem to be already defined, namely the "-" options: --fullscreen, --geometry, --list [submodules], etc.

Even if for those who don't use OpenSuSE: **Are there any flags to compctl to make it override previous settings**? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, your system is using the newer `compsys` system rather than the older `compctl` system. See `man zshcompsys` and `man zshcompwid` (and `man zshcompctl`).

The completion function for `yast2` is probably in this file (or similar path):

```
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Linux/_yast
```

Comment: beautiful, thanks much! I haven't fixed it quite yet (will do so shortly) but your answer seems pretty much spot on (/usr/share/zsh/4.3.6/functions/_yast2 for me).

Comment: Great, spent some time looking how to do it. It would be nice to overwrite the defaults (Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968024/zsh-disable-default-completion-for-make)