# ZSH: How to disable default completion for `make`?

Tags: zsh

I wrote my auto-completion function for `make` command, and placed it in `~/.zsh`:

```
function __comp_make {
    # ... function body ....
}
compctl -K __comp_make make
```

Unfortunately, it will not work because completion for `make` is already defined in

```
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_make
```

and apparently it takes precedence over my rule.

I had to rename `_make` to `unused_make` so it is not loaded at zsh initialization. It works, but it is rather ugly solution.

My question is: how should I set my completion rule so it takes precedence over the loaded defaults?

**Related:**

- [How does one override an existing zsh keyboard completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635922/how-does-one-override-an-existing-zsh-keyboard-completion)

**Edit:**

- zsh 4.3.17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your [`fpath`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html). See [here](http://zshwiki.org/home/config/functions).

In your `~/.zshrc`, something like:

```
fpath=( ~/.zshfunctions $fpath )
```

where `~/.zshfunctions` contains your custom completion files, should solve this for you. Note that your functions are loaded before the system ones. This will **not** work:

```
fpath=( $fpath ~/.zshfunctions )
```

As an aside, you're using `compctl`. It's old. I'd recommend using `compsys` instead, although a decent link explaining why escapes me at the moment.

These go into some detail about writing completion functions, including the `fpath`. You might find them useful for reference.

- [Z-shell completion functions: introduction](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33255/how-to-define-and-load-your-own-shell-function-in-zsh)
- [Writing z-shell completion functions](http://bewatermyfriend.org/p/2012/003/)

Comment: I added it to .zshrc and moved my functions to .zshfunctions, but it didn't work. It acts as it was not defined anywhere at all.

Comment: @JakubM. That's no good. When I do it, I can overwrite the default tab-completion for a command (tab completion is empty). If I follow [this](http://askql.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/zsh-writing-own-completion/), with `#compdef make` instead of `#compdef hello`, I get the custom completion on `make<tab>`. If this doesn't occur for you, I'd recommend checking: `echo $fpath`, and also checking what the contents of your completion function is. I'm not 100% sure how to do a `compctl` completion - perhaps I've missed something.

Comment: OK, following all the instructions in the blog entry, it works. Apparently that is the way to do it, and one should forget about `compctl`